# How to Register a Function without params with Spark SQL Java API

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

One can register a function using Scala:

```
spark.udf.register("uuid", ()=>java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString)
```

Now, if I use Java API:

```
 spark.udf().register("uuid", ()=>java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

The code does not compile. So how can we do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java7 or earlier version

```
sqlContext().udf().register("uuid", new UDF0() {
        @Override
        public String call() {
            return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

And if you are using java8 and later version you can use lambda

```
sparkSession.udf().register("uuid", () -> java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),DataTypes.StringType);
```